# How to sign app with iOS distribution certificate(p12) from another developer?

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile, sign, p12

I have iOS distribution certificate(p12 and private key files) from another developer.

How can I sign my app with this cetificate? I install it my keychain and now I can select right signing identity in xcode build settings tab, but can't select provision profile and development team.

What am I missing?

Comment: did you login with that account in Xcode?

Comment: You have to have a provisioning profile. You should ask for an access to Apple Developer Portal and then download the existing provisioning profile or to create a new one. If the access to the portal will be refused then you have to ask for the provisioning profile for the app.